# How to get backup of all the files having a specific format in linux

Tags: linux, grep, find, xargs

I want to copy every .ttf file to current working directory but nothing seems to happen.

I am currently using this command :

```
find / | grep .ttf | xargs cp .
```

The detection is fine, if i run `find / | grep .ttf` it gives me the exact location
of every .ttf file in my disk.
but it just doesn't work with `xargs cp .`

I already tried this method to delete every file containing a word like this:
`find / | grep chrome | xargs rm -rf`

The method is fine, So what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `cp <source> <destination>`. When you use `xargs cp .` it expands to `cp . <files found>` which is why it doesn't work.

If your `cp` supports `-t` option, you can use `xargs cp -t .` since `-t` helps you specify the destination directory. But I'd suggest to use `find+exec` and this will also avoid issues due to shell metacharacters in filenames:

```bash
find / -name '*ttf' -exec cp -t . {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single `find` command. Note that `{}` is the placeholder for the files found by `find`:

```
find / -name '*.ttf' -exec cp {} . \;
```